# Wifi router and bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

This is my first post in any blog. I got stuck with a little challenge regarding wireless routers capabilities.

Is there a way to have a wifi router that connects all my devices (wirelessly) into my local network and incorporate a wifi bridge connected to my router's WAN port that allows me connect to a hotspot? I also require the wifi bridge to be configurable (select different hotspot) without disconnecting the bridge from the router's WAN port.

Or, is there something in the market that does that? Possibly a 2 wifi antenna router: one for my wireless local network and another that connects to a wireless internet hotspot.

Thanks for your help in advance.

-Alex

Comment: I'm not sure why you're connecting your devices to the router's _WAN_ port. Could you actually explain the situation first, before rushing to the tools?

Comment: Ok, I will try to explain better:

I have a router with 4 LAN ports and 1 WAN port. I am using the router to create a local network to connect 4 devices: 1 with an ethernet cable connected to one LAN port and the other 3 via wireless. Now, i would like to have internet access for my local network through a mobile hotspot and I was thinking on adding a bridge plugged to my WAN port. The wireless bridge would be configured to detect a mobile hotspot.

Is this possible?

Regards

Comment: Yeah, that should be possible.